# How to fix Flutter 'Text Editing Controller used after being disposed' error in Stepper widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using a Stepper with five text form fields, one in the first step, two in the second step and two in the third step.  I have a different form keys for each of the three steps.  I have a suffix icon button that I use as a way to clear the text from the text form field.  I'm wondering if that is causing my problem.  Or maybe I should make each text form field a Stateful widget which I saw as a suggestion while searching SO.  I'm new to programming so I can't figure out what to do.  When I use the suffix icon to clear the text in the first step everything works fine.  I can add text again and then proceed to the next step.  Once I get to the second step or the third step the first time that I try to use the suffix icon to clear the text in the text field I get the error message:

A TextEditingController was used after being disposed.

As long as I don't use the suffix icon I can go through all three steps and upload all the data accurately to Firebase.  I have tried to remove as much of the code from below as possible to make it easier to follow.  In the code below I only show one TextEditingController, one Validator function, one listener in InitState, one method that is used to clear the text from the text field, one controller being disposed of but in the app there are five of each with the four deleted being identical to what is being shown.  If I need to show the full code I will be happy to do so.  I also removed the method used to add the data to Firestore as that works perfectly as long as I don't use the suffix icon to clear any data during the three steps.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
class AddTriviaGamePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTriviaGamePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.triviaGameID,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String triviaGameID;

  @override
  _AddTriviaGamePageState createState() => _AddTriviaGamePageState();
}

class _AddTriviaGamePageState extends State<AddTriviaGamePage> {
  final _questionFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _answerGroupOneFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _answerGroupTwoFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  FirestoreMethods firestoreMethods = FirestoreMethods();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  final TextEditingController _triviaGameQuestionController =
  TextEditingController();

  int currentStep = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _triviaGameQuestionController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  List<Step> getTriviaGameSteps() => [
    Step(
      content: AddTriviaGamePageQuestionTextField(
        formOneKey: _questionFormKey,
        suffixIcon: _triviaGameQuestionController.text.isEmpty
            ? const EmptyContainer()
            : ClearTextFieldIconButton(
          onPressed: _clearTriviaGameQuestionTextField,
        ),
        triviaGameQuestionController: _triviaGameQuestionController,
        validator: _triviaGameQuestionValidator,
      ),
      isActive: currentStep >= 0,
      state: currentStep > 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.indexed,
      title: const Text(StepperString.questions),
    ),
    Step(
      content: AddTriviaGamePageAnswerGroupOneContainer(
        answerGroupOneFormKey: _answerGroupOneFormKey,
        suffixIconAnswerOne: _triviaGameAnswerOneController.text.isEmpty
            ? const EmptyContainer()
            : ClearTextFieldIconButton(
          onPressed: _clearTriviaGameAnswerOneTextField,
        ),
        suffixIconAnswerTwo: _triviaGameAnswerTwoController.text.isEmpty
            ? const EmptyContainer()
            : ClearTextFieldIconButton(
          onPressed: _clearTriviaGameAnswerTwoTextField,
        ),
        triviaGameAnswerOneController: _triviaGameAnswerOneController,
        triviaGameAnswerTwoController: _triviaGameAnswerTwoController,
        validatorAnswerOne: _triviaGameAnswerOneValidator,
        validatorAnswerTwo: _triviaGameAnswerTwoValidator,
      ),
      isActive: currentStep >= 1,
      state: currentStep > 1 ? StepState.complete : StepState.indexed,
      title: const Text(StepperString.options),
    ),
    Step(
      content: AddTriviaGamePageAnswerGroupTwoContainer(
        answerGroupTwoFormKey: _answerGroupTwoFormKey,
        suffixIconAnswerThree: _triviaGameAnswerThreeController.text.isEmpty
            ? const EmptyContainer()
            : ClearTextFieldIconButton(
          onPressed: _clearTriviaGameAnswerThreeTextField,
        ),
        suffixIconAnswerFour: _triviaGameAnswerFourController.text.isEmpty
            ? const EmptyContainer()
            : ClearTextFieldIconButton(
          onPressed: _clearTriviaAnswerOptionFourTextField,
        ),
        triviaGameAnswerThreeController: _triviaGameAnswerThreeController,
        triviaGameAnswerFourController: _triviaGameAnswerFourController,
        validatorAnswerThree: _triviaGameAnswerThreeValidator,
        validatorAnswerFour: _triviaGameAnswerFourValidator,
      ),
      isActive: currentStep >= 2,
      title: const Text(StepperString.options),
    ),
  ];

  String? _triviaGameQuestionValidator(value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return ValidatorString.triviaGameQuestionRequired;
    }
    return null;
  }


  void _clearTriviaGameQuestionTextField() {
    setState(() {
      _triviaGameQuestionController.clear();
    });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _triviaGameQuestionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdaptiveLayoutScaffold(
      appBar: const AddTriviaGamePageAppBar(),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const AdaptiveCircularProgressCenter()
          : Stepper(
        controlsBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controls) {
          final isLastStep =
              currentStep == getTriviaGameSteps().length - 1;
          return AddTriviaGamePageButtons(
            children: [
              if (currentStep != 0)
                StepperCancelButton(
                  onPressed: controls.onStepCancel,
                ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 12.0,
              ),
              StepperNextAndConfirmButton(
                isLastStep: isLastStep,
                onPressed: controls.onStepContinue,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        currentStep: currentStep,
        onStepCancel: () {
          currentStep == 0 ? null : setState(() => currentStep -= 1);
        },
        onStepContinue: () {
          final isLastStep =
              currentStep == getTriviaGameSteps().length - 1;
          if (isLastStep) {
            uploadQuestionDataToFirestore();
          } else {
            setState(() => currentStep += 1);
          }
        },
        onStepTapped: (step) => setState(() => currentStep = step),
        steps: getTriviaGameSteps(),
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to initialize your text editing controller in initState and then dispose of it in dispose. You are initializing it just once and then disposing of it perhaps multiple times in `dispose()`.

Here is an example:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late final TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response.  I will spend time tonight working to adjust my code as you suggested.

Comment: I'm a beginner so I never doubt the knowledge of others on here.  It may take me a couple of days to work through this.  I get the same error even when initializing the text field in InitState.  In your code you removed the listener I had in InitState.  I tried it with my listener still in InitState and also removed as in your code and the error still appears when I use the suffix icon to delete the text from the text form field.  I have used the exact same approach dozens of time elsewhere in the app other than it wasn't in a Stepper.

Comment: Could you please create an example Flutter project that demonstrates your problem and post it on GitHub and give me a link to it?

Comment: Absolutely I can do that.  It will take me a day because I am traveling out of town.  I will create a Flutter project, post it to GitHub and share the link with your here.  Thank you very very much for helping me.

Comment: I posted the code to Git Hub so you can more fully see whatever you choose to look at.  I'm sure you won't need to bother with 98% of the code but I added all of the trivia game code that is finished so far to Git Hub as you requested. I posted the code to Git Hub so you can more fully see whatever you choose to look at.  I'm sure you won't need to bother with 98% of the code but I added all of the trivia game code that is finished so far to Git Hub as you requested.  https://github.com/DreamOn1227/trivia_game.git

Comment: @CarletonY thank you for this. I was hoping that you'd post a project I could clone and immediately run in Flutter but the one you've posted isn't really at that level yet. Could you please make sure the project is actually executable and reproducible? Thank you

Comment: Yes @VandadNahavandipoor.  It will take me a few days to make it able to run in Flutter as this code is part of a much larger project that is too big to post.  Thanks for your patience and help.